# Create deeply nested object from a template object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering how to go about structuring my rails relationships so that something like this is possible (note the distant relationship between Reports and Values):

```
class Report
has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
has_many :values

class Template
has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
has_many :sections

class Section
belongs_to :template
has_many :columns

class Column
belongs_to :section
has_many :fields

class Field
belongs_to :column
has_many :values

class Value
belongs_to :field
belongs_to :report
```

Is there a rails way to solve this problem? The goal is to create a Report from a Template, avoid duplicating the Template.sections.columns.fields object tree in the DB, and still have the Report contain unique Values.

Will something like rails method 'delegate' help me here somehow?

For example, could something like this work?

```
class Report
has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
has_many :sections, through: :templates
has_many :columns, through: :sections
has_many :fields, through: :columns
has_many :values
delegate :value, to: :fields
```

I don't completely understand how delegate works yet.

Another solution could be to use a kind of 3 way join table as described [on this ruby-forum post](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/88228)

```
class Report
has_many :field_values

class Field
has_many :field_values
has_many :values, through: :field_values

class Value
has_many :field_values
has_many :fields, through: :field_values

class FieldValue
belongs_to :report
belongs_to :field
belongs_to :value
```

Comment: How do these templates differ from one another?

Comment: Well the template is a template of a web form. Pretty much every class is based around some html/javascript objects on my front end for displaying the template. I'm using angularjs <div ng-repeat "section in template.sections"> then "column in section.columns"  etc... so I need something like field.value to be unique to a report. Sorry, it's hard to explain. But the differences are in the structure of the template itself. Template A has 1 section, 1 column, 3 fields. Template B has 3 sections, 1 column per section, and 4 fields per column, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was definitely not an easy, straight-forward solution, especially so with using AngularJS as a front-end. This is indeed a specific issue, but perhaps many things can be learned.

The following models and relationships are used:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
    has_many :values
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :values
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
    has_many :sections, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections
    has_many :fields, through: :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :template, inverse_of: :sections
    has_many :columns, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :columns
    has_many :fields, through: :columns
end

class Column < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :section, inverse_of: :columns
    has_many :fields, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields
end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :column, inverse_of: :fields
    has_many :values
    has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :values
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end

class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :field
    belongs_to :report
end
```

Add the following to top of reports_controller.rb (for angular-rails-templates users with models containing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31534296/1705167)):

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
  nested_attributes_names = Model.nested_attributes_options.keys.map do |key| 
    key.to_s.concat('_attributes').to_sym
  end

  wrap_parameters include: Model.attribute_names + nested_attributes_names

  # ...
end
```

To create a report using a template fields as... a template... for the report values:

```
def create
  template = current_user.templates.find(params[:template_id])
  @report = current_user.reports.new(allowed_params)
  @report.save
  @report.templates << template
  current_user.reports << @report
  template.fields.each do |field|
    @report.values.where({:field_id => field.id, :report_id => @report.id, :input => field.values.first.input }).first_or_create
  end
  render 'show', status: 201
end
```

Params for above:

```
private
  def allowed_params
    params.require(:report).permit(
      :title, :submission, :response, :active, :location,
      values_attributes: [
        :id, :report_id, :field_id, :input
      ]      
    )
  end
```

Show the report for AngularJS:

```
def show
  report = current_user.reports.find(params[:id])
  render json: report.as_json(
    :include => [:values, :templates => {
      :include => { :sections => {
        :include => { :columns => {
          :include => { :fields => {
            :include => :options
          }}
        }}
      }}
    }]
  )
end
```

In AngularJS, attach report values to appropriate template positions for display:

```
ClassFactory.get({class: 'reports', id: $routeParams.reportId}, (res)->
    jQuery.extend $scope.report, res
    $scope.report.templates.forEach((template)->
        template.sections.forEach((section)->
            section.columns.forEach((column)->
                column.fields.forEach((field)->
                    field.values = $scope.report.values.filter((obj)->
                        return obj.field_id == field.id
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Mess with the value in Angular:

```
<div ng-repeat="template in report.templates">
  <div ng-repeat="section in template.sections">
    <div ng-repeat="column in section.columns">
      <div ng-repeat="field in column.fields">
        <input type="text" ng-model="field.values[0].input" value="{{field.values[0].input}}>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update the report. Note: the values_attributes declaration is for angular-rails-templates users:

```
$scope.saveReport = ->
    $scope.report.values_attributes = $scope.form.values
    $scope.report.$update({class: 'reports', id: $scope.form.id}, (res)->
        $location.path("/reports/#{$scope.form.id}")
        $rootScope.$broadcast('clearreports')
    )
```

Typical rails update:

```
def update
  report = current_user.reports.find(params[:id])
  report.update_attributes(allowed_params)
  head :no_content
end
```

**DONE**

Like I said, I know this is really specific. Hopefully someone can learn something and/or tell me I'm bad (and why)!

**Edit**
Just realized I can slightly reduce clunkiness by adding something like this in the Create method:

```
@report.fields = template.fields
```

Then just reference $scope.report.fields in Angular, to reduce my looping. Learning in action.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your has_many :throughs that I can see.  But you won't be able to use delegate in that case - because you one Report (eventually) has many Fields, when you delegate you are delegating to a collection, not to a single object.

delegate is simply a shortcut method - for example you could delegate in the other direction:

```
class Report
  has_and_belongs_to_many :templates
  has_many :values

class Template
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
  has_many :sections
  has_many :columns, through: :sections
  has_many :fields, through: :columns

class Section
  belongs_to :template
  has_many :columns

class Column
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :fields

class Field
  belongs_to :column
  has_many :values

class Value
  belongs_to :field
  belongs_to :report
  delegates :column, to: :field
  delegates :section, to: :column
  delegates :template, to: :section
```

Then a call to @value.template is actually a call to @value.field.column.section.template - but is preferable because, obviously, it's easier to type, but also you are hiding the actual structure of your objects.

So a routine that only ever deals with values can know about the template without knowing about the hierarchy above it, which means you can change it in future with less chance of breaking existing code.

In cases like this I always draw things out - effectively you are doing Database Design, so an Entity Relationship Diagram, although old-fashioned, is exactly the right tool for the job.

[image: ERD of the data models]

I'm not entirely sure what the 3-way relationship would give you - but it depends exactly what goes into a Value - if there are lots of repeated values then Database Normalisation rules state you should extract it into a separate table (or model in Rails terms), which is what the 3-way association gets you.  But it depends what a Value is, and sometimes you have to denormalise anyway for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you so much for this perspective! I agree this is just a matter of DB design and understanding relationships. This is just more advanced than I've done before. I am curious what implications the Value has on the whole scheme. In my case, Value should just contain any IDs necessary to create relationships, and then a "key" which is the actual value associated with the Value class.